# Updating Apex Test for Apex Trigger of an installed component

Tags: apex, trigger, change-set, deployment

We recently installed a free app from AppExchange and wanted to do some minor adjustments to the Apex Trigger text when an error occurs.

To do this, we followed the simple procedure of creating a sandbox, making changes in the sandbox and deploying via change set.

However, the deployment fails because of failing Apex Tests for the updated Apex Trigger. I went ahead and tried updating the tests, but the deployment still looks at the Apex test that's already in production (not the updated one in sandbox).

Is there a way for me to deploy the updated Apex Tests to Production via change set? The deployment seems to look for a test that needs to be run during deployment that's already available in Production.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to include updated Test class in your change set. When the Change set will run it will take your updated test class instead of old class.

Also you can try run specific test class option and pass your test class name there but in this approach all classes included in change set must have coverage 75+ individually to pass the validation.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have worked. I've also specified which tests to run to speedy up the process. Thank you for your help!